# A Batch Script that copies a file do a network computer then logs if it was successful

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of computer names that i am feeding into the script form a text file and for each workstation i want to copy a text file to the desktop, then i want it to log weather or not the copy was successful or not to a different text file, currently i have 2 workstation names in the read file one that is contactable and one that is not and i am only getting one return in the log file and the workstation name is not populating.

```
SET COPIED=successful
SET WORKSTATION=XL
FOR /F %%X IN (workstations2.txt) DO copy /Y physicians.txt "\\%%X\C$\Documents and settings\All users\Desktop\physicians.txt"
SET WORKSTATION=%%X
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET COPIED="not successful"
Echo %Date% %Time% File Copy %COPIED% to %WORKSTATION% >> Logfile.txt
@echo Completed.
pause
```

here is the output from my log file

```
Tue 02/19/2013 14:02:42.74 File Copy successful to %X
```

Comment: if the solution worked, please click the UP arrow and the check mark

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your setting workstation like that, but this works for me

Note the parenthesis around the bulk of the loop

```
SET COPIED=successful
FOR /F %%X IN (workstations2.txt) DO (
    echo copy /Y physicians.txt "\\%%X\C$\Documents and settings\All users\Desktop\physicians.txt"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET COPIED=not successful
    Echo %Date% %Time% File Copy %COPIED% to %%X >> Logfile.txt
)
@echo Completed.
pause
```